# I need to find the lead time/no.of days it took from bill sent to payment received from the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query where I should find the lead time/ time taken from billsent to payment received for the transactions in the given table. I have the detail explanation of table below, have a look.

Step 1:  create a table "T_Account_Details" with 3 columns AccountId, TransactionDate, ActionTaken.  (1001, 1002, 1003 .......)and(6/1/2013,6/4/2013,7/1/2013......)and(billsent, paymentReceived....) 
Step 2:  There might be some "Action taken"s that correspond to the previous "billsent"s . We should not consider these records. 
step 3: Find the turn time between bill sent and payment received.

In this way I have 200 rows, for some accountid's there is only billsent and no payment recieved, and for some accountid's there is only payment received but no bill was sent, and for some accountid's the billsent date is greater than the payment recieved date.

So, for all this criteria's I need to find the turn time/lead time/time taken from billsent to payment received. As I am new to sql server, its bit complex for me, can you please help me out.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select account_id,date_bill,date_pay,datediff(day,date_bill,date_pay) 'Lead time' 
from
    (
        select account_id,
            (select transactionDate from T_Account_Details x where ActionTaken='billsent' and x.account_id = account_id) date_bill,
            (select transactionDate from T_Account_Details x where ActionTaken='paymentReceived' and x.account_id = account_id) date_pay
        from T_Account_Details
    ) T
order by account_id
```

Comment: Hi, When I query this, I am getting this error, have a look.

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: No accountid is not unique, as there other transactions too with same acountid, so accountid column is not unique